# Need help weighting (scaling) each of the bins in a histogram by a different factor

Tags: python, matplotlib

I'm trying to make a histogram of the radial distribution of a circular scatterring of particles, and I'm trying to scale the histogram so that the radial distribution is in particles per unit area.

> **Disclaimer**: If you don't care about the math behind what I'm talking about, just skip over this section:
>
> I'm splitting the radial distribution in to annuluses of equal width, going out from the center. So, in the center, I will have a circle of some radius, a. The area of this inner most portion will be $\pi a^{2}$.
>
> Now if we want to know the area of the annulus going from radial distance a to 2a, we do $$ \int_{a}^{2a} 2 \pi r \ dr = 3 \pi a^{2} $$
>
> Continuing in a similar fashion (going from 2a to 3a, 3a to 4a, etc.) we see that the areas increase as follows: $$ Areas = \pi a^{2}, 3 \pi a^{2}, 5 \pi a^{2}, 7 \pi a^{2}, ... $$
>
> So, when I weight the histogram for the radial distribution of my scatter, going out from the center, each bin will have to be weighted so that the count of first bin is left alone, the count of the second bin is divided by 3, the count of the third bin is divided by 5, etc, etc.

So: Here's my try at the code:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# making random sample of 100000 points between -2.5 and 2.5
y_vec = 5*np.random.random(100000) - 2.5
z_vec = 5*np.random.random(100000) - 2.5

# blank canvasses for the y, z, and radial arrays
y_vec2 = []
z_vec2 = []
R_vec =  []

# number of bins I want in the ending histogram
bns = 40

# cutting out the random samplings that aren't in a circular distribution
# and making the radial array
for i in range(0, 100000):
        if np.sqrt((y_vec[i]*y_vec[i] + z_vec[i]*z_vec[i])) <= 2.5:
                y_vec2.append(y_vec[i])
                z_vec2.append(z_vec[i])
                R_vec.append(np.sqrt(y_vec[i]*y_vec[i] + z_vec[i]*z_vec[i]))

# setting up the figures and plots
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
fig2, hst = plt.subplots()

# creating a weighting array for the histogram
wghts = []
i = 0
c = 1

# making the weighting array so that each of the bins will be weighted correctly
# (splitting the radial array up evenly in to groups of the size the bins will be
# and weighting them appropriately). I assumed the because the documentation says
# the "weights" array has to be the same size as the "x" initial input, that the 
# weights act on each point individually...
while i < bns:
        wghts.extend((1/c)*np.ones(len(R_vec)/bns))
        c = c + 2
        i = i + 1

# Making the plots
ax.scatter(y_vec2, z_vec2)
hst.hist(R_vec, bins = bns, weights = wghts)

# plotting
plt.show()
```

The scatter plot looks great:
[image: Scatter]

But, the radial plot suggest that I got the weighting wrong. It should be constant across all annuli, but it is increasing, as though it were not weighted at all:
[image: RadialDist]

The erratic look of the Radial Distribution suggests to me that the weighting function in the "hist" operator weights each member of R_vec individually instead of weighting the bins.

How would I weight the bins by the factors I need to scale them by? Any help?

Comment: Is there are a reason you need to use `hist` instead of just directly computing the particles per unit area in each annulus and plotting a bar graph?

Comment: Also, are you using Python 2?  If so, are you using `from __future__ import division` so that divisions with integers will return fractions?  Otherwise the problem may just be that `1/c` is truncated to 0, so your weights are all getting set to zero.  Can you print out the weights and verify that they are what they should be?

Comment: @BrenBram Because I thought I would have to create 40 different arrays, sort all of the points in R_vec in to the appropriate arrays, weight them, and plot them somehow, and I thought that would an unnecessary/inelegant way of doing it, but I might just look in to that next if what I'm asking turns out not to be possible.

Comment: @BrenBam I'm using Python 2.7 and the most recent matplotlib (scypy) distro. I adding the "from __future__ import division" to the top of my script and it did not make a difference to the plots. Also, earlier while I was debugging my weighting idea, I made sure that the weighting array and the R_vec array were the same size (they had to be or else ".hist" would crashed and told me to make them the same size). And I made sure they were what I wanted them to be.

Answer (score 0):

You are correct when you surmise that the weights weight the individual values and not the bins.  This is [documented](http://matplotlib.org/api/pyplot_api.html#matplotlib.pyplot.hist):

> Each value in x only contributes its associated weight towards the bin count (instead of 1).

Therefore the basic problem is that, in calculating the weights, you aren't taking account of the order of the points.  You created points at random, but then you create the weights in sequence from greatest to least.  This means you're not assigning the right weights to the right points.

The way you should create the weights is by directly computing each point's weight from its radius.  The way you seem to want to do this is by discretizing the radius into a binned radius, then weighting inversely by that.  Instead of what you're doing for the weights, try this:

```
R_vec = np.array(R_vec)
wghts = 1 / (2*(R_vec//(2.5/bns))+1)
```

This gives me the right result:

[image: histogram]

You can also get essentially the same result without doing the binning in the weighting --- that is, just directly weight each point by the reciporcal of its radius:

```
R_vec = np.array(R_vec)
wghts = 1 / R_vec
```

[image: histogram]

The advantage of doing this is that you can then plot a histogram a different number of bins without recomputing the weights.  It also makes somewhat more conceptual sense to weight each point by how far out it is in a continuous sense, not by whether it falls on one side or the other of a discrete bin boundary.

Comment: Excellent response thank you! Can I ask where you got this?: wghts = 1 / (2*(R_vec//(2.5/bns))+1)

Comment: @D.W.: That is just your area weighting done in a more compact way.  Since your max radius is 2.5, `2.5/bns` is the width of each annulus.  `R_vec//(2.5/bns)` is the "ring number" (i.e., which radial bin we are in, the 0th, 1st, 2nd, 3rd, etc.).  Taking 2n+1 gives the appropriate odd number to generate the weights of 1, 3, 5, 7. . .

Answer (score 0):

When you want to plot something "per unit area", use area as your independent variable. 
This way, you can still use a histogram if you like, but you don't have to worry about non-uniform binning or weighting.

I replaced your line:

```
hst.hist(R_vec, bins = bns, weights = wghts)
```

with:

```
hst.hist(np.pi*np.square(R_vec),bins=bns)
```

[image]